# How to send money using blockchain API?

Tags: transactions, api, blockchain.info

I am not very familiar with php but I just want to know how this works. I am trying to use the blockchain API to send some money for testing purposes but the transaction isn't taking place. My current code is this :-

```
<?

$guid="xxxxxxxx";
$main_password="xxxxxxxx";
$amount = "50000";
$to = "xxxxxxxx";


$json_url = "https://blockchain.info/merchant/$guid/payment?password=$main_password&second_password=$second_password&to=$address&amount=$amount&from=$from&shared=$shared&fee=$fee&note=$note";

$json_data = file_get_contents($json_url);

$json_feed = json_decode($json_data);

$message = $json_feed->message;
$tx_hash = $json_feed->tx_hash;

?>
```

Please tell me what is the error in my code and also how to print out the response on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use all the optional variables in your request link, specially when you have not set a second password, etc...

this suffice the request to send your transaction:

```
$json_url = "https://blockchain.info/merchant/$guid/payment?password=$firstpassword&to=$addressa&amount=$amounta&fee=$fee";
```

even if you remove "fee" variable, it would still work but you should consider 0.0001 miners fee that is there by default for minimum miners fee.

also you can get these values from the response:

```
$json_feed = json_decode($json_data); 

$message = $json_feed->message; 
$txid = $json_feed->tx_hash; 
$notice = $json_feed->error;
```

Comment: and what happens if I purposely put a wrong address?

Comment: it would send the btc to the wrong address...

Comment: you can add a "from=$addressb" to your request to indicate which address you are sending bitcoins from.

Comment: I meant an invalid address. And how do I print the message on screen with tx hash?

Comment: you would get the following fields in the response json:
$json_feed = json_decode($json_data);
$message = $json_feed->message;
$txid = $json_feed->tx_hash;
$notice = $json_feed->error;

Comment: But when I enter an address and run the php, I get no result.

Comment: @Shayanbahal better put the code of your comment into your answer otherwise its rly hard to read